# The selector did not match any elements while using component in Router

Tags: angular, webpack

I am not used to Angular 2 routers that much. I have written a HomeComponent and it is working fine for me.
Now when i am using it in router the it gets displayed in the  by the components name (not by selector). Thus my page output has Homecomponent by not using its selector that is defined in its decorator.

Now i am getting a warning that selector "main-home" did not match any elements.

Kindly suggest how can i remove this error. Shall i change my page component structure.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about-us', component: LoginComponent}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-home',
  templateUrl: './home.compoment.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

**Error/warning**

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "main-home" did not match any elements
ErrorHandler.handleError
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: The selector "main-home" did not match any elements
```

/*** Updated***/

Now i tested the same with SystemJS setup and no error is coming up. This problem is only with webpack setup. Kindly suggest how can this error be removed/avoided.

check this code on plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MasUPOPbakYULpWIOX6w?p=preview

Comment: Could you post all of your code somewhere?

Comment: This problem is only with webpack see the link below:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MasUPOPbakYULpWIOX6w?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

I got this error too
finally i found that i bootstrap some component that did not using in index.html
i fixed the error by removing these components from AppModule's bootstrap list